IllegalStateException: ApplicationContext failure
I have spring boot application with 3.1.2 version and trying to migrate spring boot to the latest version i.e 3.3.2.
But I am facing problem while running Test Suite.
I am using TestNG v7.4.0
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>7.4.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

I have abstract class which extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTtests
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:service-data-context.xml"})
@TestExecutionListeners({DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class})
@Transactional
public abstract class ServiceAbstractDaoTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {
...

}

Inside service-data-context.xml , I have declared all the bean classes. I have one more class which extends ServiceAbstractDaoTest
public class DaoImplTest extends ServiceAbstractDaoTest {
    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;
   
    @Test
    public void testUser() {
    ...
    }
}

If I try to build the project with maven clean install, I am getting below error
[ERROR] springTestContextPrepareTestInstance(com.service.dao.DaoImplTest)  Time elapsed: 0.02 s  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationContext failure threshold (1) exceeded: skipping repeated attempt to load context for [MergedContextConf
iguration@1183e952 testClass = com.service.dao.DaoImplTest, locations = ["classpath:service-data-context.xml"], classes = [], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = [], propertySourceDescriptors = [], propertySourceProperties = 
[], contextCustomizers = [org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@4b6d92e, org.springframework.boot.test.json.Du
plicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@e9ef5b6, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCus
tomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustom
izer@1f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.
servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizer@6069dd38], contextLoader = org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader, parent = null] 

[ERROR] springTestContextBeforeTestMethod(com.service.dao.DaoImplTest)  Time elapsed: 0.043 s  <<< FAILURE!  
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationContext failure threshold (1) exceeded: skipping repeated attempt to load context for [MergedContextConf
iguration@1183e952 testClass = com.service.dao.DaoImplTest, locations = ["classpath:service-data-context.xml"], classes = [], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = [], propertySourceDescriptors = [], propertySourceProperties = 
[], contextCustomizers = [org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@4b6d92e, org.springframework.boot.test.json.Du
plicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@e9ef5b6, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCus
tomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustom
izer@1f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.
servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizer@6069dd38], contextLoader = org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader, parent = null] 

[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
[ERROR] Failures: 
[ERROR] com.service.dao.DaoImplTest.springTestContextBeforeTestMethod(com.service.dao.DaoImplTest)
[ERROR]   Run 1: DaoImplTest>AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.springTestContextBeforeTestMethod:131 » IllegalState
[ERROR]   Run 2: DaoImplTest>AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.springTestContextBeforeTestMethod:131 » IllegalState
[ERROR]   Run 3: DaoImplTest>AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.springTestContextBeforeTestMethod:131 » IllegalState
[ERROR]   Run 4: DaoImplTest>AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.springTestContextBeforeTestMethod:131 » IllegalState
[ERROR]   Run 5: DaoImplTest>AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.springTestContextBeforeTestMethod:131 » IllegalState
[INFO]
[ERROR]   DaoImplTest>AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.springTestContextPrepareTestInstance:119 » IllegalState
[ERROR] com.service.dao.DaoImplTest.springTestContextBeforeTestMethod(com.service.dao.DaoImplTest)
[ERROR]   Run 1: DaoImplTest>AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.springTestContextBeforeTestMethod:131 » IllegalState
[ERROR]   Run 2: DaoImplTest>AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.springTestContextBeforeTestMethod:131 » IllegalState
[ERROR]   Run 3: DaoImplTest>AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.springTestContextBeforeTestMethod:131 » IllegalState
[ERROR]   Run 4: DaoImplTest>AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.springTestContextBeforeTestMethod:131 » IllegalState
[ERROR]   Run 5: DaoImplTest>AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.springTestContextBeforeTestMethod:131 » IllegalState
[ERROR]   Run 6: DaoImplTest>AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.springTestContextBeforeTestMethod:131 » IllegalState
[ERROR]   Run 7: DaoImplTest>AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.springTestContextBeforeTestMethod:131 » IllegalState
[ERROR]   Run 8: DaoImplTest>AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.springTestContextBeforeTestMethod:131 » IllegalState
[ERROR]   Run 9: DaoImplTest>AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.springTestContextBeforeTestMethod:131 » IllegalState

Stack trace while running the test suite:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext for [MergedContextConfiguration@f45efe8 testClass = com.service.dao.impl.DaoImplTest, locations = ["classpath:service-data-context.xml"], classes = [], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = [], propertySourceDescriptors = [], propertySourceProperties = [], contextCustomizers = [org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@76c3e77a, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@2a54a73f, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@1f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizer@17497425], contextLoader = org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader, parent = null]

    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:180)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:142)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:260)
    at org.springframework.test.context.testng.AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.springTestContextPrepareTestInstance(AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.java:119)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:62)
    at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:385)
    at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:321)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:176)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:794)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:596)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:377)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:371)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:332)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:276)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1212)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1134)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1063)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:66)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:105)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [service-data-context.xml]: [PersistenceUnit: rc360-wsa-pu] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.query.NamedQueryValidationException: Errors in named queries: 
  [1] Error in query named 'getAssetDetailOfUser': Cannot compare left expression of type 'java.lang.String' with right expression of type 'java.lang.Object'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:600)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1234)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:952)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:624)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:221)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:110)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:212)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:225)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:152)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: rc360-wsa-pu] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.query.NamedQueryValidationException: Errors in named queries: 
  [1] Error in query named 'getAssetDetailOfUser': Cannot compare left expression of type 'java.lang.String' with right expression of type 'java.lang.Object'
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:421)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:366)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1833)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.query.NamedQueryValidationException: Errors in named queries: 
  [1] Error in query named 'getAssetDetailOfUser': Cannot compare left expression of type 'java.lang.String' with right expression of type 'java.lang.Object'
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.NamedObjectRepositoryImpl.validateNamedQueries(NamedObjectRepositoryImpl.java:230)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryEngineImpl.validateNamedQueries(QueryEngineImpl.java:215)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryObserverForNamedQueryValidation.sessionFactoryCreated(SessionFactoryObserverForNamedQueryValidation.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryObserverChain.sessionFactoryCreated(SessionFactoryObserverChain.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:315)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:450)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1507)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:142)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409)
    ... 48 more
    Suppressed: org.hibernate.query.SemanticException: Cannot compare left expression of type 'java.lang.String' with right expression of type 'java.lang.Object'
        at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.TypecheckUtil.assertComparable(TypecheckUtil.java:358)
        at org.hibernate.query.sqm.tree.predicate.SqmComparisonPredicate.<init>(SqmComparisonPredicate.java:48)
        at org.hibernate.query.sqm.tree.predicate.SqmComparisonPredicate.<init>(SqmComparisonPredicate.java:34)
        at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.createComparisonPredicate(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:2448)
        at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitComparisonPredicate(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:2392)
        at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitComparisonPredicate(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:269)
        at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$ComparisonPredicateContext.accept(HqlParser.java:6164)
        at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitAndPredicate(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:2262)
        at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitAndPredicate(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:269)
        at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$AndPredicateContext.accept(HqlParser.java:6039)
        at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitAndPredicate(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:2261)
        at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitAndPredicate(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:269)
        at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$AndPredicateContext.accept(HqlParser.java:6039)
        at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitWhereClause(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:2244)
        at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitWhereClause(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:269)
        at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$WhereClauseContext.accept(HqlParser.java:5905)
        at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitQuery(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:1159)
        at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitQuerySpecExpression(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:941)
        at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitQuerySpecExpression(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:269)
        at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$QuerySpecExpressionContext.accept(HqlParser.java:1869)
        at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitSimpleQueryGroup(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:926)
        at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitSimpleQueryGroup(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:269)
        at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$SimpleQueryGroupContext.accept(HqlParser.java:1740)
        at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitSelectStatement(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:443)
        at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitStatement(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:402)
        at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.buildSemanticModel(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:311)
        at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.StandardHqlTranslator.translate(StandardHqlTranslator.java:71)
        at org.hibernate.query.internal.NamedObjectRepositoryImpl.lambda$checkNamedQueries$5(NamedObjectRepositoryImpl.java:252)
        at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl$1.translate(QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.java:111)
        at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.createHqlInterpretation(QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.java:165)
        at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.resolveHqlInterpretation(QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.java:147)
        at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.resolveHqlInterpretation(QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.java:107)
        at org.hibernate.query.internal.NamedObjectRepositoryImpl.checkNamedQueries(NamedObjectRepositoryImpl.java:249)
        at org.hibernate.query.internal.NamedObjectRepositoryImpl.validateNamedQueries(NamedObjectRepositoryImpl.java:219)
        ... 57 more

Can anyone please help me to understand why I am getting NamedQueryValidationException when the spring boot is migrated to 3.3.2 from 3.1.2?

Can you please attach the declaration of getAssetDetailOfUser query and the annotated repository method? It seems that the issue is in validating that. I remember a similar error in a project, when we upgraded Spring Boot to 3.2.x: query validators are more strict for auto-fitting method parameters into query and types that are compared.

problem was in the @NamedQuery
@NamedQuery(name="getAssetDetailOfUser", 
query = "select assetDetails ad where ad.userId IN 
(select u from User u where u.id IN (:id))")

After upgrading spring boot to 3.2.4, its supporting hibernate version is 6.4.x.
This version does the strict check on query expression where it expects the same data type in the named query. 
In the above query, we should correct the second SELECT statement as
(select u.id from User u where u.id IN (:id))

upgraded hibernate version does not do the implicit data binding.
Discussed more on this issue in Validation failed for query, cannot compare left expression of type with right expression of type
