JdbcTypeRecommendationException: Could not determine recommended JdbcType for
I have searched all over the internet, these tricks do not fix my problem.  Here is my entity (simplified version):
@Entity
@Table(name = "msg")
public class InternalMessage implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3768430013233258L;


    @PrePersist
    public void genTicketId() {
// something
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "internal_msg_parent_fk", nullable = true)
    private InternalMessage parent = null;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        private List<InternalMessage> childMessages = new ArrayList<>();
}


I don't see any problems, and this worked fine before I migrated to Spring boot 3 (hibernate 6).
So what could be the issue?
Edit:
Mysql: 8.0.33
Spring boot: 3.3.3
Vscode 1.92.2
gradle: 8.10

Same result run the app in debug mode in vscode, or command line: ./gradlew bootRun
OK, I have some idea, seems the following code if failing:
public Predicate toPredicate(Root<InternalMessage> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query,
                CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
            List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

            if (search == null || search.trim().isEmpty()) {
  // this part is causing me issue
                Expression<InternalMessage> parent = root.get("parent").as(InternalMessage.class);
                Predicate p = criteriaBuilder.isNull(parent);
                predicates.add(p);
                query.distinct(true);
                return criteriaBuilder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
            } else {
// this part works
            }

        }

and this is the line causing the exception:
                Expression<InternalMessage> parent = root.get("parent").as(InternalMessage.class);

Anything wrong with the above line?  It worked in older spring boot/hibernate.

Can you provide in details what spring boot version you using. Provide maven/gradle configuration file. Also, provide which database you using? I tried your code with spring boot 3.3.2 and h2 database no errors found.

Thanks Dhaval, just updated the post with detailed versions.

Can you also provide some more lines of the exception stack trace, please?

@FrancescoPoli added.  But had to remove the dependencies.

ok, removed bottom part of the stack trace and added dependencies.

OK, updated with more information

I noticed this only after your last update: the join column (where I suppose is persisted the id of the parent) is called "parent" and the InternalMessage attribute is also called "parent"? May this aliasing lead Hibernate to misdjudge what is managing, and then trying to process the parent instance incorrectly? Indeed it is Hibernate's fault, in this case...

Just for curiosity's sake... have you tried to set @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT", nullable = true) (mind the upper case of the column name)?

Thanks @FrancescoPoli, that is not the case, for simplicity I used 'parent', but the column name is actually a different name: internal_msg_parent_fk.  I am updating the post now.

Why do you model your entity bidirectional? Is there a use case which can't be covered by modeling it top-down (only holding the childMessages) (parent can still be part of the table!).

@ValerijDobler  Originally I only have the parent, I don't have the List..., and it worked fine in spring boot 2.6.4 (which was the version before the migration).  I only added the second part because of the exception I'm facing now (and some posts says that could solve the issue, but it did not)

I managed to replicate your error locally. I created an implementation of the Specification interface so to have almost the same toPredicate method and the context usage. I confirm also that the error originates from the line:
Expression<InternalMessage> parent = root.get("parent").as(InternalMessage.class);

Anyway, I have been able to solve the problem replacing the lines:
Expression<InternalMessage> parent = root.get("parent").as(InternalMessage.class);
Predicate p = criteriaBuilder.isNull(parent);

With this single statement, removing the intermediate Expression step:
Predicate p = criteriaBuilder.isNull(root.get("parent"));

I am not sure if this leads to the correct data extraction, but I can see that the sql statement that is generated in junit tests is:
select distinct im1_0.id,im1_0.internal_msg_parent_fk from msg im1_0 where im1_0.internal_msg_parent_fk is null

That seems what is required in the original toPredicate method.
Let me se if this solves the problem in your application.
For the sake of completness, the original method seems to work if Long is used instead of InternalMessage, in this way:
Expression<Long> parent = root.get("parent").as(Long.class);

but I think that the above solution is clearer, also because using this approach the generated select statement is this:
select distinct im1_0.id,im1_0.internal_msg_parent_fk from msg im1_0 where cast(im1_0.internal_msg_parent_fk as bigint) is null

where there is this cast(... as bigint) that is quite unnecessary, in this case.

Thanks @Francesco!!!  This indeed solved the problem.  Both suggestions work!  Yes, first one is simpler and better.  I think this may relate to this issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78913982/  and  https://stackoverflow.com/a/76522587/14072498
Thanks a lot!!!

Yes, indeed. Maybe it's the same side effects of these other questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78844558 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77648311, what a mess...
